# Calculating two different averages in C++

Tags: c++, average, dev-c++

My assignment is to calculate bowling averages. I have five players, and three games for each player. I currently have two loops running, one for the player, and the other for the game number. I need to show the players average at the end of each of those loops, and the teams average at the end of that loop.

I fixed my code, and replaced my old code with the new code below. I was playing with it before I checked here to see everyones comments etc, and I had solved it by then.

But thank you to everyone!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//DECLARATIONS
const int PLAYER_NUMBER = 5; //There are five players total
const int GAME_NUMBER = 3; //There are three games total
const int MIN = 0; //Min number
const int MAX = 300; //Max number
double* playerScore; //The players' score of current game
double playerAverage = 0; //The current players' average
double teamAverage = 0; //The teams' average

//INPUT

for (int currentPlayer = 0; currentPlayer < PLAYER_NUMBER; currentPlayer++)
{//Set the current player number  

    for (int currentGame = 0; currentGame < GAME_NUMBER; currentGame++)
    {//Set the current game number
             //Get scores

             cout << "For Player " << (currentPlayer + 1) << ", enter score for game " << (currentGame + 1) << ": ";
             cin  >> playerScore[currentGame];


             if(playerScore[currentGame] < MIN || playerScore[currentGame] > MAX)
             {//Check range
                   cout << "The score must be between 0 and 300!\n";
                   currentGame--; //If there is an error, subtract the game number by one
             }//End If statement

             playerAverage += playerScore[currentGame];

             if(currentGame == 2)
             {//Current player average
                cout << endl << "The average for player " << (currentPlayer + 1) << " is: " << (playerAverage / 3) << endl << endl;
                teamAverage += playerAverage;
                playerAverage = 0;
             }//End If statement

    }//End game for-statement

}//End player for-statement

    cout << endl << "The average for the team is: " << (teamAverage / 15) << endl << endl;

//ENDING    
system("Pause");
return 0;    
}//Close main
```

But, for anyone still there, is there a way to just have the terminal left open, and not having to use "sys("PAUSE");"? I really hate using it.

Comment: If the cin executes successfully, the lines below it execute.  I suspect that you're seeing some debugger artifact that makes it seem like the cin is executing and not the lines below.

Comment: Thank you to everyone! I was fiddling with the code right after I posted this, and I somehow got it to work by moving some lines around. I think it may be a fluke. The next time I go to code something like this, I will definitely screw it up :P

Comment: Sometimes the problem is simply that you forgot to save the source file, or it didn't get recompiled automatically when you rebuilt things.  These things can be very frustrating.

Comment: I would definitely say that the debugger built in to Dev-C++ is horrible. I wish it could show me values and stuff the same way Visual Studio does. Maybe it does, I haven't really looked. And yeah, things definitely can get very frustrating, but so far C++ has been much easier than c# was last semester.

Answer (score 6):

You're declaring `double* playerScore`, but I don't see where you're allocating the storage. Perhaps you're overwriting something.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. Don't declare a pointer for later allocation unless the assignment specifically calls for it. You know how many elements the array needs, declare it on the stack.

Comment: I declared the pointer there because I was told that I should declare everything at the top that will be used later on so it's accessible everywhere. And for the longest time (only like 5 days actually) I thought I was working with arrays again, but I don't think so now?

Comment: Anyways, the pointer is to point to the value being put in at playerScore[currentGame]. I use it there to say that the user is putting in the player's score at whatever number the game is.

Comment: You can use a pointer to "create" an array (or a single variable) using `new`. By itself a pointer is just a pointer.

Comment: I kind of picked through the uncommented samples from class, and some textbook material, and I thought I was making an array with the `*` originally. I have been using C++ for like two weeks. I wasn't good with arrays in C#, either, unfortunately. I still don't get them.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop wont check for the last game number or player number.

Isn't `system("pause")` bad just for holding open the console? You can avoid using `system("pause")` by using something like `std::cin.get()` or `getchar()`.

You also made `playerScore` a pointer and using it without the `*` before it so you are actually trying to get the address of whatever it is pointing to (in this case nothing--it didn't even get allocated).

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
/* ... */
double* playerScore; //The players' score of current game

for (int currentPlayer = 0; currentPlayer < PLAYER_NUMBER; currentPlayer++) {
    for (int currentGame = 0; currentGame < GAME_NUMBER; currentGame++) {
             cout << "For Player " << (currentPlayer + 1) << ", enter score for game " << (currentGame + 1) << ": ";
             cin  >> playerScore[currentGame];
```

When you're writing into `playerScore[currentGame]`, you're writing into memory that was never allocated. I don't know what you're scribbling on, but it isn't yours to write into.

You should allocate memory for `playerScore`. You'll have to decide the best way to allocate the memory, but something like:

```
double playerScore[PLAYER_NUMBER];
```

might be a good starting point.

Incidentally, this is something your compiler probably would warn you about; you might need to turn on more warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` are my favorite flags to `gcc` -- your compiler may need something different) but it should be able to warn you about this. While you won't need to fix *every* compiler warning, don't just ignore them -- there's thousands of years of programming experience distilled in modern compilers.

Comment: +1 for *warnings*. Every teacher should warn about turning warnings on *on the very first class*.

Comment: @R.Martinho: though until you've spent an hour trying to find a mistake like this, it might be hard advice to take. :)

Comment: If I was going to allocate the number, it would be more like 
`double playerScore[PLAYER_NUMBER*GAME_NUMBER];// or 15`
and thanks about the warnings, I don't have anything showing up in dev-c++ so I thought everything was good

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few problems here:

- You never allocate any space for your array. Your `playerScore` needs a `new` somewhere.
- `cin >> playerScore[currentGame]` will only ever write array indicies 0, 1 and 2. This logic needs to combine currentPlayer and currentGame somehow.
- Same with `playerAverage += playerScore[currentGame];`
- You'll need to `delete[]` the space you allocate with `new` after you're done with your `playerScore` array.

Comment: No, it doesn't need a `new`. The size is fixed at compile-time.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, I'm well aware you know the size at compile time and can allocate on the stack. However, perhaps he's been told to use dynamic allocation here. I decided to go with the least changes needed.

Comment: The solution with the least changes involves using a static array.

Comment: Pointers don't in general need `new` but they do need something to point at which he never does.

Comment: Never mind that this is nitpicking, and there are actual logic errors that no-one else bothered to point out.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing the input in an unknown location. I'm surprised you haven't encountered a segfault yet.

`double* playerScore;` doesn't necessarily declare an array, it's a "pointer to a double". You can use it to create an array on the heap (`playerScore = new double[SOME_SIZE];`).

Until you actually tell the pointer where to point using it is like using any other uninitialized variable, there is no telling what it actually contains. The difference is instead of interpreting the bytes stored there as an int, double, etc. it is interpreted as a memory address and you attempt to write to that location in memory.

Since you know how many values you need to store I would just declare a static array `double playerScore[SOME_SIZE]`

Comment: You seem like you know what you're doing, unlike me. Funny thing is, once I changed the order of the `if statements` and put `playerAverage += playerScore[currentGame];` between them, and put `teamAverage += playerAverage` in the `if(currentGame == 2)` block before `playerAverage = 0;`, it fixed my problem, and I ran through it a couple times, and the math was right at the end. 
But thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: When overwriting arbitrary memory locations you often get a segfault by trying to write over some location that is protected. If coincidentally the location isn't protected it can actually end up working. The problem is when the code that was actually supposed to use that memory location executes and the data is changed. Could be that it is going to overwrite and no-harm-no-foul. Or it could be depending on the value there and something bizarre happens.